# TypeORM - add object to OneToMany relations

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, typescript, typeorm

I have a `user` and `project` entity with `OneToMany` relations between them,

user.entity.ts

```
  @ManyToOne(() => Project, pro => pro.members, {
    nullable: true
  })
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'userId',
  })
  member: Project;
```

project.entity.ts

```
  @OneToMany(() => User, user => user.member)
  members: User[]
```

function to add user to project:

```
    async addMemberToProject(projectId: number, memberEmail: string): Promise<void> {
        const project = await this.conn.getRepository(Project).findOne({
            where: {
                id: projectId
            }
        }).catch(() => {
            throw new BadRequestException("Project not found!");
        });

        const user = await this.getUserByEmail(memberEmail).catch(() => {
            throw new BadRequestException("User not found!");
        })

        if(user !== null) {
            project.members.push(user);
            await this.conn.getRepository(Repository).save(project).catch(() => {
                throw new BadRequestException("Member not added to project!");
            });
        }
    }
```

why when I try to add user to project, my compiler throw me:

```
Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

What i'm doing wrong? Maybe I have a bad database logic? (User can be in many projects, project can have many users), Can someone help me? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

`@JoinColumn` on the `user.entity` looks wrong, it should be named: `projectId`, assuming the primary key of `Project.entity` is `projectId`.

The reason for you error is you need to add `relations: ['members']` to project `findOne()`

```
const project = await this.conn.getRepository(Project).findOne({
    where: {
        id: projectId
    },
    relations: ['members']
})
```

Without this, TypeORM does not populate "project.members": project.members is undefined, so `project.members.push(user)` causes an "undefined" error.